# jQuery ajax post fired twice

Tags: jquery, browser

I'm doing a $.post to a page using jquery, the problem is this post executed twice when ever its fired, I've tried to run the page in IE and firefox, the result is the same, and using firebug shows that the request is bieng submitted twice.

I need your help please, thanks in advance. 
Here is the code:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    //Reply buttons binding live event
    $(".ticketButton").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        //build dialog with id & title
        $( "#msgs-form:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
        var ticket_ID= $(this).attr("title");
        var ticket_title= $(this).attr("msgTitle");
        $("#msgs-dialog").attr("title", ticket_title);

        //fetch data from the server to fill dialog content
        $.post("server_processing_tickets_response.php", {'getTickets' : ticket_ID},
                function(data){
                var div_data;
                //build div's of classes .ticket-1 and ticket-0 from the returned json object
                $.each(data.tickets_data, function(i, tickets_data)
                    {
                    div_data += "<div class='ticket-0'><span>" + tickets_data.content + "</span></div>";
                    });
                $(div_data).appendTo("#ticketsWrap");
                }, "json");

        $("#msgs-form #ticketID").attr("value", ticket_ID);
                $( "#msgs-dialog" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: ticket_title,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 460,
                    show: "fade",
                    hide: "fade",
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: false,
                    close: resetDialog()
                });

        $( "#msgs-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });

    function resetDialog(){
    $("#ticketsWrap").empty();
    }
```

}

thanks for your fast reply!
Here is the full javascript code I'm using:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
$('#real-content').showLoading();
    }).ajaxStop(function(){
$('#real-content').hideLoading();
    });

//ajax forms submission
$(function() {      

        var msgs_table = $('#msgs_table').dataTable( {
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bProcessing": false,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "server_processing_msgs.php",
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "aoColumns": [ 
                                    { "sWidth": "30px" },
                                    { "sWidth": "100px" },
                                    { "sWidth": "200px" },
                                    { "sWidth": "250px" },
                                    { "sWidth": "50px" }
                            ],
                "oLanguage": {
                                "sProcessing": "...تحميل",
                                "sZeroRecords": "لايوجد لديك تذاكر حالياً",
                                "sInfoEmpty": "",
                                "sInfoFiltered": "",
                                "sInfo": "يتم إظهار _START_ إلى _END_ من _TOTAL_ تذكرة",
                                "oPaginate": {
                                                "sFirst":    "البداية",
                                                "sPrevious": "السابق",
                                                "sNext":     "التالي",
                                                "sLast":     "النهاية"
                                              },
                                "sSearch": "بحث ضمن التذاكر:",
                                "sLengthMenu": "عرض _MENU_ تذكرة"

                             },
                "aoColumnDefs": [{
                        "fnRender": function ( oObj ) {
                                        return "<input type='button' style='padding:3px 6px;'  name='ticket-ID-button' value='عرض' msgTitle='" + oObj.aData[3] + "\' title='" + oObj.aData[0] + "\' class=\"ticketButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only\" />";  
                                    },
                            "aTargets": [ 0 ]}]
            } );



    jQuery().ready(function() {

                $( "#ٍSucsessMessage" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 300,
                    show: "fade",
                    hide: "fade",
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: false,
                });
                $( "#ٍFailMessage" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 300,
                    show: "fade",
                    hide: "fade",
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: false,
                });


    //Reply buttons binding live event
    $(".ticketButton").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        //build dialog with id & title
        $( "#msgs-form:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
        var ticket_ID= $(this).attr("title");
        var ticket_title= $(this).attr("msgTitle");
        $("#msgs-dialog").attr("title", ticket_title);

        //fetch data from the server to fill dialog content
        $.post("server_processing_tickets_response.php", {'getTickets' : ticket_ID},
                function(data){
                var div_data;
                //build div's of classes .ticket-1 and ticket-0 from the returned json object
                $.each(data.tickets_data, function(i, tickets_data)
                    {
                    div_data += "<div class='ticket-0'><span>" + tickets_data.content + "</span></div>";
                    });
                $(div_data).appendTo("#ticketsWrap");
                }, "json");

        $("#msgs-form #ticketID").attr("value", ticket_ID);
                $( "#msgs-dialog" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: ticket_title,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 460,
                    show: "fade",
                    hide: "fade",
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: false,
                    close: resetDialog()
                });

        $( "#msgs-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });

    function resetDialog(){
    $("#ticketsWrap").empty();
    }

    $( "#msgs-reply-button" ).click(function() {
        $("#msgs-form").submit();
        $("#msgs-dialog").dialog( "close" );
    }); 

    //reply form ajax submit
    $("#msgs-form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.post("server_processing_tickets_response.php", $("#msgs-form").serialize(),
        function(data){
            if(data.valid == 'valid'){ 
                $( "#ٍSucsessMessage" ).dialog( "open" );
                setTimeout(function(){$( "#ٍSucsessMessage" ).dialog("close")},1500);
            }
            else if(data.valid == 'invalid')
            {
                $( "#FailMessagee" ).dialog( "open" );
                setTimeout(function(){$( "#FailMessagee" ).dialog("close")},3000);
            }
        }, "json");

    });
    //Reply buttons in table//
```

Is it something related to request header?
here is the headers i get form firebug after I submit the form :
    Response Headers
Date    Sat, 09 Jul 2011 13:29:51 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Length  24
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=84
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html
Request Headers
Host    127.0.0.1:8888
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://127.0.0.1:8888/Lightc-tables/msgs.php
Content-Length  41
Cookie  PHPSESSID=ku8e6o3h2bl27ltofkir58a626

and the same headers with different Expires also repeated after this headers..

Comment: Try debugging your code in firebug or chrome

Comment: Bakk is this issue resolved? If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some little trigger-hoak ;)

```
$(".ticketbutton").unbind("click");
$(".ticketbutton").unbind("live");
$(".ticketbutton").die();
```

Comment: so according to the business logic sometimes it won't work for the system. It works as a function but not really helping my side because I have a very complex system!